# x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS

Tags: boot, sgx

I reboot my computer to find this error:

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
```

[image]

I tried several solutions, but nothing worked. I tried using Ubuntu from a bootable USB, but it seems that it does not recognize the SSD and the Ubuntu installation that is already installed.

[image]

Results of `sudo lsblk -f` :

[image]

Comment: Not a problem, just ignore it. And don't try "solutions" you don't understand as they likely will create problems. Again, that message is harmless.

Comment: The message you showed is not the problem/has nothing to do with the problem. If your computer is not booting, then that is a problem. To confirm: the first screenshot shows what happens if you do nothing and just let it boot? Or does it boot normally if you just turn on the PC?

Comment: I dosn't boot. It gets stuck in that first image.

Comment: Boot up a live system and show us `sudo lsblk -f` [edit] your question for output, please.

Comment: @nobady. Thaks for you help. I have edited the question to include the result of  'sudo lsblk -f'

Comment: yep you are right, no harddrive seen. Is harddrive show up in Bios/Uefi menue?

Comment: I have precisely the same problem rn, did you find a solution?

Comment: please change your title. It is completely irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: It boots the initramfs from the disk, which is not seen by the system. How can this be? Disk "half" broken?

Answer (score 0):

`x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS` is not an error, it just a statement said SGX is not in use. Normally if you do not know what is SGX that means you did not use it for anything.

The real problem is the last line about a disk partition you try to mount does not exist. Please `cat /etc/fstab` and post it here. So we can help you further.

Inside the busybox you are always root. So there is no `sudo`. You are in initramfs stage. That means your `/boot` is properly recognized. But your rest partition for example the `/` present in the fstab in initrd does not exist.

Your command in the ubuntu live does not make any sense: your sda1 is your usb stick apparently. Your command shown that you remount and update your live system. From your lsblk you do not have any other disk install in your system. Please make sure your internal disk is correctly connected or powered up and enabled in the bios.

Please tell us what kind internal disk do you have. sata, nvme or other.